# Why can't we use `\` to escape special characters in html ...?

Tags: html, escaping

like in many other languages.

For example to use the special html character `<` we use `&lt` instead of `\<`.  Just curious why the break from normal escape methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply due to the way the encoding has been written. While some languages such as `Java` and `C++` use `\`-escaping, HTML uses `%`-escaping.

As for *why* this is the case, `URL` uses [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) due to the fact that the `\` character is typically used to handle paths and parameters. Therefore, the `%` escape character would considered "normal" for HTML.

Comment: HTML uses `&`-escaping for HTML text entities, and URLEncoding for URLs, but mostly it just treats `%` as a string/char literal.

Comment: ... paths in urls are forward slashes ( / ) not back slashes ( \ ).  I don't understand your reasoning.